# Mysql error "mysql server has gone away"

Tags: mysql

Estoy con win10 - gx9 - vfp9 sp2 - MariaDB , y cuando el exe  deja de ejecutare por unos minutos (porque se minimizo por ej. 15 minutos) , al tratar de acceder a la bd tira el error:

> Error:2006. The text for the message is: "[MYSQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.0.22-MariaDB-log] MYSQL server has gone away

Revise/reconfigure  timeout y otras configuraciones  que he visto en don Google, pero no logro solucionar el tema.

El servidor tiene otras bd que se acceden por ej. por java web  no hay problema, el lio es con VFP Win ODBC, la conexión por windows cliente-servidor es diferente a la de aplicaciones web, en c/s la conexión es "permanente" digamos, entonces mientras los usuarios estan trabajando no hay problema, cuando no usan el pgm. por 10-15 min aparece el error y deben ingresar nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Modifiqué todas las variables de la base de datos que sugerían en google y se corrigió. Los nuevos valores son:

```
connect_timeout = 100000
net_read_timeout = 100000
wait_timeout = 100000
interactive_timeaout = 100000
```

Comment: También que exageraste  en lo valores. Sólo cuida en no afectar el rendimiento de la base de datos si es que tiene muchas conexiones.

Comment: ¿Qué hacen las variables que cambiaste? ¿Cómo afectan los nuevos valores? Lee sobre [answer] donde encontrarás más información sobre cómo escribir respuestas completas. Un saludo.